# How can I use Monte Carlo Dropout in a pre-trained CNN model?

Tags: deep-learning, monte-carlo-methods, dropout, uncertainty-quantification, mc-dropout

In Monte Carlo Dropout (MCD), I know that I should enable dropout during training and testing, then get multiple predictions for the same input $x$ by performing multiple forward passes with $x$, then, for example, average these predictions.

Let's suppose I want to fine-tune a pre-trained model and get MCD uncertainty estimations, how should I add dropout layers?

- on the fully-connected layers;
- after every convolutional layer.

I've read some papers and implementations where one applies dropout at fully-connected layers only, using a pre-trained model. However, when using a custom model, usually one adds dropout after every convolutional layer. This [work](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.00792) builds two configurations:

- dropout on the fully-connected layers;
- dropout after resnet blocks.

The first configuration performs better, but I'm unsure if this is an actual uncertainty estimation from resnet. The results show that there is a correlation between high uncertainty predictions and incorrect predictions. So, would this be a good way of estimating uncertainty? My shot is "yes", because even though there are no nodes being sampled from the backbone, the sampling in the fully-connected layer forces a smooth variation in the backbone, generating a low-variance ensemble. But, I'm quite a beginner on MCD so, any help would be appreciated.